# ERROR: Failed building wheel for mpi4py, Could not build wheels for mpi4py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, mpi, python-wheel, mpi4py, pep517

I am trying to install packages for a project in conda environment. I have issues in building wheel for mdp4py package. The package is installed but couldnt build a wheel for it.

The error code is too long but looks something like this....

```
Building wheel for mpi4py (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
.......
  checking for library 'vt.ompi' ...
  gcc -pthread -B /home/devmurari/anaconda3/envs/DiSS/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  gcc -pthread -B /home/devmurari/anaconda3/envs/DiSS/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ _configtest.o -lvt.ompi -o _configtest
  /home/devmurari/anaconda3/envs/DiSS/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lvt.ompi
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  failure.

.......
_configtest.c:2:10: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
      2 | #include <mpi.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  error: Cannot compile MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mpi4py
Failed to build mpi4py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mpi4py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Tried doing it manually by pip but issue persists....

Comment: A requirement is a MPI library with development headers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41446426/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmpi4py%5D+fatal+error%3A+mpi.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory Also see https://pypi.org/project/mpi4py/ on how to install from Conda.